# Itirating through a list of words and calculate accuracy of typing off a high-lighted word

Tags: java

I trying to see where the logical error is in my code. I want to print out a list of words, some of which are highlighted in yellow. I should type off the highlited words and arrive at accuracy of my action. It does not calculate properly, could you please check?

Thanks in advance!

```
public void colourGame(Players players) {
    startTime = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Type the following characters: ");
    List<String> originalWords = generateRandomEnglishWords(25);
    List<String> highlightedWords = generateRandomEnglishWordsWithColour(4);

    StringBuilder wordString = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : highlightedWords) {
        wordString.append(word).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(wordString.toString().trim());
    System.out.println("\nBegin typing now!");

    System.out.println("Enter your words: ");
    String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] typedWord = inputLine.split("\\s+");

    double accuracy = calculateAccuracyColouredGame(typedWord, highlightedWords);
    endTime = Instant.now();
    if (accuracy == 100.0) {
        calculateTime(players);
    }
}

public List<String> generateRandomEnglishWordsWithColour(int numberOfWords) {
    List<String> englishWords = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
    return highlightEnglishWordsInYellow(englishWords, numberOfWords);
}

private List<String> highlightEnglishWordsInYellow(List<String> words, int numberOfWords) {
    List<String> highlightedWords = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
        String word = words.get(random.nextInt(words.size()));
        if (random.nextBoolean()) {
            word = TerminalColors.YELLOW + word + TerminalColors.RESET;
        }
        highlightedWords.add(word);
    }
    return highlightedWords;
}

public double calculateAccuracyColouredGame(String[] typedWords, List<String> originalWords) {
    int totalHighlightedWords = 0;
    int correctHighlightedWords = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < typedWords.length && i < originalWords.size(); i++) {
        String typedWord = typedWords[i];
        String originalWord = originalWords.get(i);


        if (originalWord.contains(TerminalColors.YELLOW)) {
            totalHighlightedWords++;


            if (typedWord.equalsIgnoreCase(originalWord)) {
                correctHighlightedWords++;
            }
        }
    }


    double accuracy = totalHighlightedWords == 0 ? 0.0 :
            (double) correctHighlightedWords / totalHighlightedWords * 100.0;

    accuracy = Math.round(accuracy * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println("Accuracy for highlighted words: " + accuracy + "%");


    return accuracy;




}
```

I ran debugg and it seems that the for-loop does not recognise highlited words and does not count them